# How to strip host information from an hdfs path

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, filepath

I have an hdfs path `hdfs://host1:8899/path/to/file`. I want to strip the `host1` and port programmatically. As result, it should be `hdfs:/path/tofile`.  Is there  any helper method can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Is there any helper method can do that?"

Doesn't really take much to create your own. Just use the basic String class utility functions like `split()`, `indexOf()`, `substring()`, etc.

Something like this would do (with Java, though most languages have those methods):

```
public class TestPath {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String path = "hdfs://localhost:9000/path/to/file";
        System.out.println(getPathWithoutHostAndPort(path));
    }

    public static String getPathWithoutHostAndPort(String path) {
        String[] array = path.split("(//)");
        int indexOfFirstSlash = array[1].indexOf("/");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(array[0]).append(array[1].substring(indexOfFirstSlash));
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

> Result: `hdfs:/path/to/file`

Comment: You function looks good. If there is no any existing functions to do that, I'll be happy to accept the answer.